# How to use gitKraken to update backend and front end at the same time

Tags: git, github, gitkraken

Right now I have two repos on github: one for the front end and one for the backend. I also have to seperate gitkraken repos that update each one when a change is made to to the backend or the frontend. This is the only way I could get Gitkraken to work with my project currently. Is it possible however to keep the front end and backend together in the same gitkraken file? I would like to do that so I can also have the frontend and backend together in the same repo on Github.